# C++ Is using files in Binary mode better or worse then text mode?

Tags: c++, file, security, text, binary

Besides speed, which i understand is variable based on machines. Is there an advantage to  text mode or binary mode when it comes to using (reading/writing) data to and from files. Are there restrictions about mobility of files from one system to another? security?

Comment: This is an implementation defined problem.  Do you have an actual problem or do you want to discuss the merits of the different line endings?  Do you have any piece of code you re concerned about?

Comment: I've got basic file read/write code and I'm having different file sizes but both files seem to work just fine. So I wanted to get a little more information if I were to move those files (to a different system or share them cross platform) if issues would arise.

Comment: A textual representation of a number has no issues with Big Endian or Little Endian.  Also, a floating point value stored as text representation doesn't depend on internal representation (such as the number of bytes to represent it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between binary and text access is who does the interpretation of a sequence of bytes in a stream.

- When you use binary mode, the task of interpreting the sequence of bytes is entirely yours: your program gets access to "raw" bytes, and that is that.
- When you use text mode, the standard library takes on the task of interpreting bytes as a sequence of characters for you. The standard does not guarantee cross-system portability of this interpretation, but it will be correct for the system for which your program is compiled.

Another thing to note is that all text files can be processed in binary mode, while opening binary files in text mode may be problematic.

In general, if you need a portable text encoding, you should access files in binary mode and do interpretation yourself, or use a custom library that would do it for you.

Comment: Note that there is no encoding being done like in many other languages that are character-encoding aware (e.g. utf-8). The text-mode interpretation is *extremely* simple.